# An interface 10 methods and I want to implements only 5 methods ,But condition is that we can not use abstract class

Tags: java

If An interface A have 100 methods and I want to implements only 10 methods of interface A,But condition is that I can not use abstract class Kindly help me with a solution

Comment: Find an existing abstract or complete implementation?

Comment: Could you implement the other 90 methods also and throw a UnsupportedOperationException for each one of them?

Comment: You can do that in Java 9

Comment: This is patently impossible. Please read the tutorials on interfaces as they will explain why. I suspect that you are either misinterpreting your instructions or have a sadistic instructor. Rather than wander down a blind alley, consider posting your *exact* instructions so that we can help you better understand them.

Comment: maybe he needs to go back to the drawing board

Answer (score 2):

> If An interface A have 100 methods and I want to implements only 10
>   methods of interface A

That's not how interfaces work. They're contracts. Every method in an interface is both `abstract` and `public`, and therefore you need to give implementations for each one.

Now, if you were using abstract base classes with 100 methods, you could give default implementations to 90 of them, and then make the other 10 purely `abstract`.

And as a final note. 100 methods on an interface is a bit too epic. Consider hacking that guy into smaller pieces :p

Comment: Starting with Java 8, methods in interfaces can have default implementation, so it is not guaranteed that every method is abstract.

Comment: Well, true, but i'm assuming OP isn't using java 8.

Answer (score 0):

**No Solution.**

`Interface` is designed in such way that the implementing class except `abstract` class must `override` the all interface  methods.

Answer (score 0):

Two choices:

1. Extend another class that implements the interface. And simply
   override only those methods that you want to implement.
2. Don't extend any other class. Implement the 10 methods completely and provide empty body implementation for other methods.

Comment: Don't extend any other class. Implement the 10 methods completely and provide empty body implementation for other methods - This is also implementation right?. implementing "doing Nothing". :) . He wants to implement only 10 methods.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a good idea to split this interface in multiple smaller interfaces and the current big interface could easily extend all these small pieces of interfaces if you really need this big one. Having 100 methods is probably way too much anyway, I guess that the classes implementing it have very low cohesion.

If a class can only do 10 actions out of 100, it doesn't really respect the contract. Think about a bank contract. What if you signed a paper for receiving 100k $ but you only got 10k $ ? It doesn't seem right/correct, does it? But if you sign a 10k paper and you get 10k as promised, you're satisfied right?

Another solution is adapter. Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html . This class implements all the mouse listeners(empty methods) and if you need only 1, 2 or just a couple overriden, you just extend this class and implement the ones you need, but still, there are 3 smaller interfaces, not a big one to do everything.

Also, starting with Java 8, methods in interfaces can have default implementation, so you can provide an empty method implementation directly in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Split 100 method interfaces into small meaningfull interfaces **X[]** and let the 10 methods you want to use be in a single interface **A**

Now your class **C** can implement just **A**, which is what you need.

In class **Z** where you want to implement all 100 interfaces. You have 2 solution

1. Extend all the interfaces in **X[]** in single interface **B** and then implement it in **Z**
2. Implement all **X[]** interfaces in  **Z**

***Conclusion***: You need to restructure your interfaces and split them into smaller interfaces. 100 method interface is difficult to maintain and indicates bad design.

Answer (score 0):

You can offer something like this

```
    Iterator i = new Iterator() {
        int[] a = {1,2,3};
        int i = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return i < a.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object next() {
            return a[i++];
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented");
        }
    };
```